# Transformation: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, asp.net, casting

I've seen questions similar to mine but my approach is slightly different and I am not familiar enough with C# to put it together. I am using the following code in an ASPX transformation:

```
  <%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Eval("XYZ")) ? "<tr>XYZ</tr>" : "" %>
```

The error comes up when the field is null because it cannot be converted to a string. How do I re-write this to check for a null value without converting to a string before the actual check? There might be a limitation in the CMS that I'm using which would explain why the previous dev did not use another approach, but I will test your suggestions.

Comment: `(string)Eval("XYZ")`? what is that?

Comment: Eval("XYZ") == System.DBNull  || string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Eval("XYZ")) ? "" : "<tr>XYZ</tr>"

Comment: XYZ is the field name, (string)Eval is a function that gets the value of the field from the database and tries to convert it to a string. This is where the error is coming from when the field is null.

Comment: Don't cast it then...

Comment: @met.lord then the call to `IsNullOrEmpty` will fail.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment thank you for the suggestion but I got this error: 'System.DBNull' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context - not sure if this is from .NET or the CMS. The approach suggested by NineBerry worked though so no worries :)

Comment: Right but, what about <%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("XYZ") != null ? "<tr>XYZ</tr>" : "" %>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(Eval("XYZ"))) ? "<tr>XYZ</tr>" : "" %>
```

DBNull is a special value when reading from the database that tells you that you have read from an empty value in the database. The Convert class does already deal with DBNull values correctly. Convert.ToString(DBNull value) will return an empty string.

Comment: This worked, much appreciated! The CMS IntelliSense is not recognizing the Convert.ToString class and method but it seems to be working as expected. Btw I'm not awesome enough to +1 yet so anyone viewing this please do eeet.